# A sequential Do for scheme (do*)

Tags: loops, variable-assignment, sequential, chicken-scheme

In Common Lisp, there's a sequential form of `(do *vars* *test* *body*)`; just like *let*'s sequential parallel `let*`, it works through `*vars*` one at a time, so that you can refer back to previously defined variables like so:

```
(do* ((a '(1 2 3) (cdr a))
      (b (mapcar (lambda (x) (1+ x)) a) (cdr b)))
     ((= 1 1) (list 'a a 'b b)))
; (a (1 2 3) b (2 3 4))
```

In Scheme, AFAIK, there is no correlating function or macro. There's `do`, but no `do*`.  I've been trying to write an implementation of `do*` for Chicken Scheme, but so far I'm struggling to make any headway... I think, I can't really tell.  I'm familiar with Chicken Scheme, but I've always found scheme macros confusing.

Here's what I've got so far:

```
(##sys#extend-macro-environment
 'do*
 '()
 (##sys#er-transformer
  (lambda (form r c)
(##sys#check-syntax 'do* form '(_ #((symbol _ . #(_)) 0) . #(_ 1)))
(let* ((bindings (cadr form))
       (test (caddr form))
       (body (cdddr form))
       (do*var (r 'doloop)))
  `(let*
       ,do*var
     ,(##sys#map (lambda (b) (list (car b) (car (cdr b)))) bindings)
     (##core#if ,(car test)
        ,(let ((tbody (cdr test)))
           (if (eq? tbody '())
               '(##core#undefined)
               `(##core#begin ,@tbody) ) )
        (##core#begin
         ,(if (eq? body '())
              '(##core#undefined)
              `(##core#let () ,@body) )
         (##core#app
          ,do*var ,@(##sys#map (lambda (b)
                     (if (eq? (cdr (cdr b)) '())
                         (car b)
                         (car (cdr (cdr b))) ) )
                       bindings) ) ) ) ) ) ) ) )
```

But I keep on getting errors like `doloop` not being a list--presently, I'm getting

```
Error: during expansion of (do* ...) - in `do*' - symbol expected: (do* ((a (quote (1 2 3)) (cdr a)) (b (map (lambda (x) (+ 1 x)) a) (cdr b)) ((= 1 1) (list (quote a) a (quote b) b))))

    Call history:

    <syntax>          (do* ((a (quote (1 2 3)) (cdr a)) (b (map           (lambda (x) (+ 1 x)) a) (cdr b)) ((= 1 1) (list (quote a) a...
    <eval>    (##sys#check-syntax (quote do*) form (quote (_ #((symbol _ . #(_)) 0) . #(_ 1))))     <--
```

Here's a rough `do*` in Common Lisp taken from [HyerSpec](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_do_do.htm#doST):

> ```
>   (block nil        
>    (let ((var1 init1)
>      (var2 init2)
>      ...
>      (varn initn))
>      declarations
>      (loop (when end-test (return (progn . result)))
>        (tagbody . tagbody)
>        (psetq var1 step1
>           var2 step2
>           ...
>           varn stepn))))
> ```
>
> do* is similar, except that let* and setq replace the let and psetq, respectively.

And here's what `do*` expands to in CL:

```
(expand-form '(do* ((a '(1 2 3) (cdr a))
        (b (mapcar (lambda (x) (1+ x)) a) (cdr b)))
           ((= 1 1) (list 'a a 'b b))))
(block nil
   (let* ((a '(1 2 3)) (b (mapcar #'(lambda (x) (declare (system::source ((x) (1+ x)))) (1+ x)) a)))
     (tagbody #:loop-5382 (if (= 1 1) (go #:end-5383)) (setq a (cdr a) b (cdr b)) (go #:loop-5382) #:end-5383 (return-from nil (list 'a a 'b b))))) ;
;t
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, do not use ##-prefixed identifiers.  Those are unsupported and **not** part of the official API!

Second, instead of trying to mess about with low-level macros, just use syntax-rules, which is much simpler, less error-prone and standardized.  It should be used whenever you don't need to break hygiene.

Here is an example of do* as it would work if I understand you correctly:

```lisp
(define-syntax do*
  (syntax-rules ()
    ((_ ((?var0 ?init0 ?inc0) ...)
         (?test ?result)
         ?body ...)
     (let* ((?var0 ?init0) ...)
       (let lp ()
         (cond (?test ?result)
               (else ?body ...
                     (set! ?var0 ?inc0) ...
                     (lp))))))))
```

Expressed as an implicitly renaming macro:

```lisp
(define-syntax do*
  (ir-macro-transformer
   (lambda (e i c)
     (let* ((vars (cadr e))
            (test&result (caddr e))
            (test (car test&result))
            (result (cadr test&result))
            (body-exprs (cdddr e)))
       `(let* (,@(map (lambda (v) (list (car v) (cadr v))) vars))
          (let lp ()
            (cond (,test ,result)
                  (else ,@body-exprs
                        ,@(map (lambda (v) `(set! ,(car v) ,(caddr v))) vars)
                        (lp)))))))))
```

I hope you agree it is much more verbose that way.

Comment: I do agree that it is much more verbose; part of my problem is that I started on Common Lisp: macros, though _very_ verbose, were very straight-forward looking, even primitive as far as hygiene is concerned: even the implicit and explicit macro renaming transformers for scheme look confusingly complex in comparison.

Comment: What's so complex about the ir-macro-transformer?  It's basically identical to a Common Lisp macro.  The only difference is the fact that the arguments aren't destructured automatically. But we also have an egg which provides a [safe, hygienic version of define-macro](http://wiki.call-cc.org/eggref/4/bindings#define-macro). It's based on implicit renaming macros, I think.

Comment: By the way, the updated version of do* in your "missing" repository is slightly wrong: it uses a tail pattern for the result ("test ..."), but strictly speaking that indicates there may be zero or more tests followed by a result, whereas it really should be one test followed by zero or more (or one or more?) result expressions. I also see you removed the question marks from the pattern variables. This is of course your own decision, but it is sort of idiomatic to use question marks for clarity, to distinguish pattern variables from identifiers that are introduced in the resulting expression.